# Recursive wget crawling for two directories

Tags: html, recursion, wget, web-crawler

I am having trouble getting Wget to follow links properly. It gets all the files necessary to render the page and even includes external links as long as they are in the same parent directory. Unfortunately it is not retrieving external links embedded in the page if they are on the same domain but different directory. I only need to go one level on the link, but it is further complicated by the fact that the links I want have no index.html for the directory (i.e. direct link).

Here is what I have so far:

`wget -r -m -k -K -p -np -nH --cut-dirs=4 -R --adjust-extension -P games/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d) http://www.website.org/export/sites/admin/games/types/ http://www.website.org/export/sites/admin/games/types/`

This basically crawls the directory and retrieves all files (mostly HTML files). It works *perfectly* and gets everything I need with exception to files directly linked to within the retrieved contents.

Say it retrieves `85393283_poker.html` - and in that file is a link: `http://www.website.org/export/sites/admin/documents/tables/secondarytables.pdf` (notice this is different directory)

Well, it won't retrieve that file. For every HTML file retrieved from the first query, it contains a link of the second query. Bottom line is that it won't retrieve the second link.

I've been looking all over but can't seem to figure it out. Have tried separate `wget` queries but again because `/tables` doesn't have html or index it won't crawl.

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the --no-parent option, which blocks any traversal above/beside your current directory.  Since the second file is in a different directory (and not a child directory of the first), it won't crawl it.

What you'll need to do is combine -I and -X, or --accept-regex/--reject-regex to craft a more specific crawl.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out! Took lots of trial and error though